# Get only (or compile only) Bootstrap Grid

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bower

I'm trying to incorporate Twitter Boostrap into a project, but only the fluid grid system.

Ideally, I'd be able to pull this from bower and install it that way. Otherwise, I'd like to be able to compile it directly inside of bootstrap's less. I'm basically trying to avoid downloading the file and removing the parts I don't need.

Has anyone had experience with this? Right now, I'm running the following command inside bootstrap:

```
 grunt dist-css
```

Which is giving me all of the compiled. Is it possible to isolate the grid?

Comment: goto http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and deselect all but those features / components you want to include in your bootstrap .. (??)

Comment: Completely true. I guess initially I was looking for a more programatic way of going about it but that also works. I wonder if there's a way to pass those options into bower?

Comment: I guess you could pull down the source and work on a way of automating the customizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with this link and choose only those components which you need or you can open bootstrap's css file and delete everything besides class container,container-fluid,row,row-fluid and classes that start with name col.
Hope this is useful for you.

**http://getbootstrap.com/customize/**